# Custom handler for custom message

Tags: webforms

I have a Webform (6.x) with style *Cards*, and *Ajax*.

I would like the users to be able to personalize the message shown as confirmation of the form, with paragraphs and the like.

With a regular webform we have implemented a custom handler with a redirect to a node.
With the Cards/Ajax it would be interesting to show the content of that node (configured in the handler) as a confirmation message.

Any suggestion on how we could, from a custom handler, I guess that with the `confirmForm` function, "catch and replace" the confirmation message?

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution myself after debugging. Leaving it here for further reference: based on https://git.drupalcode.org/project/webform/-/blob/6.1.x/src/Plugin/WebformHandlerBase.php#L607

```php
public function preprocessConfirmation(array &$variables) {}
```

Implementing this we can easily modify the message as a simple "markup" element in

```php
$variables['message']
```

Comment: It works is most cases except when I've to show message in modal dialog box.